# Tracking checkins from generic users

Tags: linux, source-code

Im trying to implement a better system to monitor checkins to our repository. We have some generic users everyone can use, I have recently disallowed them from checking in as those users however there is one user that is used in our builds who must be able to checkin.

I would still like people to be allowed to become that user to sort build issues but its still open to people anonymously checking in changes as that user.

Im kind of stumped for an elegant solution to this without having to restructure a lot of things. My ideal outcome seems incompatible with itself: The generic user existing and doing its thing as well as knowing who made every check in.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You have answered your own question: the system of generic accounts is a mess, and totally lacks **accountability**. You really have to switch to personalized accounts.